# Get time before noon

Tags: php, date

I am practicing with dates in php. I a bit of a newbie so bear my ignorance
I am trying to see when a time is before noon.
So I have a variable coming in with this format `2014-03-07 13:28:00.000`

I get the time like this

`$submissonTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($value['job_submission_date']));`

then I want to set another variable as `$noon` and i am doing this:

```
$noon = date('H:i:s', '12:00:00.000');
```

However the value of `noon` is  12:00:12

what i want to do is basically:

```
if($submissionTime <= $noon){
  //do my stuff
}
```

NB I want to enter the if statement when even when it is 12:00:00 and stop entering when it is 12:00:01

Any help please?

Comment: Use the `DateTime` class. http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: `date('H:i:s', '12:00:00.000');` second argument of `date` is a timestamp, not a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$noon = date('Y-m-d 12:00:00'); // today noon with date
$submissonTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($value['job_submission_date']));
if(strtotime($submissonTime) <= strtotime($noon)){
  //do my stuff
}
```

if you want to compare only time use both format

```
$noon = date('12:00:00'); 
$submissonTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($value['job_submission_date']));
```

Comment: Why are you computing `submissonTime`? Just use `strtotime($value['job_submission_date'])`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (date("A") == "AM")
{
  // AM-Code
} else {
  // PM-Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go with only one string of code getting the hour?

```
$Hour = date("G"); //24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros

if($Hour < 12) {
    // do the code
}
```

Or in your case

```
$Hour = date("G", strtotime($value['job_submission_date']));
```

**update**

If you need 12:00:00 and not 12:00:01 and later on, you will need to define minutes and seconds:

```
$Hour = date("G"); //24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros
$Minute = intval(date("i")); // will give minutes without leading zeroes
$Second = intval(date("s"));

if(($Hour < 12) || ($Hour == 12 && $Minute == 0 && Second == 0)) {
        // do the code
    }
```

Comment: I think this way we don't enter the 'if' when it is 12:00:00. However, i need to enter the if also when it is 12:00:00 and stop entering when it is 12:00:01